# javascript fullcalendar datetime is messed up

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, fullcalendar

I am following this tutorial on making a calendar scheduler in asp.net MVC5:
http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2017/07/curd-operation-on-fullcalendar-in-aspnet-mvc.html

I am having trouble understanding how the datetime is passed and why it is showing the min value in the database (as if the value were null because left empty): specifically it is set to 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM in the database.

I have looked into various answers on Stack Overflow but do not know how or what I need to change to make the datetime be set to a non null value.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Here is the javascript in my index view

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var events = [];
            var selectedEvent = null;
            FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
            function FetchEventAndRenderCalendar() {
                events = [];
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/home/GetEvents",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                            events.push({
                                eventID: v.EventID,
                                title: v.Subject,
                                description: v.Description,
                                start: moment(v.Start),
                                end: v.End != null ? moment(v.End) : null,
                                color: v.ThemeColor,
                                allDay: v.IsFullDay
                            });
                        })

                        GenerateCalender(events);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert('failed');
                    }
                })
            }

            function GenerateCalender(events) {
                $('#calender').fullCalendar('destroy');
                $('#calender').fullCalendar({
                    contentHeight: 400,
                    defaultDate: new Date(),
                    timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
                    },
                    eventLimit: true,
                    eventColor: '#378006',
                    events: events,
                    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                        selectedEvent = calEvent;
                        $('#myModal #eventTitle').text(calEvent.title);
                        var $description = $('<div/>');
                        $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Start:</b>' + calEvent.start.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                        if (calEvent.end != null) {
                            $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>End:</b>' + calEvent.end.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                        }
                        $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Description:</b>' + calEvent.description));
                        $('#myModal #pDetails').empty().html($description);

                        $('#myModal').modal();
                    },
                    selectable: true,
                    select: function (start, end) {
                        selectedEvent = {
                            eventID: 0,
                            title: '',
                            description: '',
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            allDay: false,
                            color: ''
                        };
                        openAddEditForm();
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                    },
                    editable: true,
                    eventDrop: function (event) {
                        var data = {
                            EventID: event.eventID,
                            Subject: event.title,
                            Start: event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A'),
                            End: event.end != null ? event.end.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A') : null,
                            Description: event.description,
                            ThemeColor: event.color,
                            IsFullDay: event.allDay
                        };
                        SaveEvent(data);
                    }
                })
            }

            $('#btnEdit').click(function () {
                //Open modal dialog for edit event
                openAddEditForm();
            })
            $('#btnDelete').click(function () {
                if (selectedEvent != null && confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '/home/DeleteEvent',
                        data: {'eventID': selectedEvent.eventID},
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.status) {
                                //Refresh the calender
                                FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('Failed');
                        }
                    })
                }
            })

            $('#dtp1,#dtp2').datetimepicker({
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A'
            });

            $('#chkIsFullDay').change(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $('#divEndDate').hide();
                }
                else {
                    $('#divEndDate').show();
                }
            });

            function openAddEditForm() {
                if (selectedEvent != null) {
                    $('#hdEventID').val(selectedEvent.eventID);
                    $('#txtSubject').val(selectedEvent.title);
                    $('#txtStart').val(selectedEvent.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A'));
                    $('#chkIsFullDay').prop("checked", selectedEvent.allDay || false);
                    $('#chkIsFullDay').change();
                    $('#txtEnd').val(selectedEvent.end != null ? selectedEvent.end.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A') : '');
                    $('#txtDescription').val(selectedEvent.description);
                    $('#ddThemeColor').val(selectedEvent.color);
                }
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                $('#myModalSave').modal();
            }

            $('#btnSave').click(function () {
                //Validation/
                if ($('#txtSubject').val().trim() == "") {
                    alert('Subject required');
                    return;
                }
                if ($('#txtStart').val().trim() == "") {
                    alert('Start date required');
                    return;
                }
                if ($('#chkIsFullDay').is(':checked') == false && $('#txtEnd').val().trim() == "") {
                    alert('End date required');
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    var startDate = moment($('#txtStart').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A").toDate();
                    var endDate = moment($('#txtEnd').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A").toDate();
                    if (startDate > endDate) {
                        alert('Invalid end date');
                        return;
                    }
                }

                var data = {
                    EventID: $('#hdEventID').val(),
                    Subject: $('#txtSubject').val().trim(),
                    Start: $('#txtStart').val().trim(),
                    End: $('#chkIsFullDay').is(':checked') ? null : $('#txtEnd').val().trim(),
                    Description: $('#txtDescription').val(),
                    ThemeColor: $('#ddThemeColor').val(),
                    IsFullDay: $('#chkIsFullDay').is(':checked')
                }
                SaveEvent(data);
                // call function for submit data to the server 
            })

            function SaveEvent(data) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/home/SaveEvent',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.status) {
                            //Refresh the calender
                            FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                            $('#myModalSave').modal('hide');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Failed');
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    </script>
}
```

And here is my Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace FamilyCalendar2.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult GetEvents()
        {
            using (Entities1 dc = new Entities1())
            {
                var events = dc.Event.ToList();
                return new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SaveEvent(Event e)
        {
            var status = false;
            using (Entities1 dc = new Entities1())
            {
                if (e.EventID > 0)
                {
                    //Update the event
                    var v = dc.Event.Where(a => a.EventID == e.EventID).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (v != null)
                    {
                        v.Subject = e.Subject;
                        v.Start = e.Start;
                        v.End = e.End;
                        v.Description = e.Description;
                        v.IsFullDay = e.IsFullDay;
                        v.ThemeColor = e.ThemeColor;
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    dc.Event.Add(e);
                }

                dc.SaveChanges();
                status = true;

            }
            return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult DeleteEvent(int eventID)
        {
            var status = false;
            using (Entities1 dc = new Entities1())
            {
                var v = dc.Event.Where(a => a.EventID == eventID).FirstOrDefault();
                if (v != null)
                {
                    dc.Event.Remove(v);
                    dc.SaveChanges();
                    status = true;
                }
            }
            return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the event class looks like:

```
namespace FamilyCalendar2
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Event
    {
        public int EventID { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> End { get; set; }
        public string ThemeColor { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsFullDay { get; set; }
        public string User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I should mention: if i copy and paste the source into my project the datetime issue is still there. This makes it seem to me that maybe there is an issue with my nuget packages or something? I am somewhat new to VS2017

Comment: Can u debug this code? So u can see where the problem is? in the beginning of your post method, what value do you see for your DateTime props?

Comment: {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM} this is the start time in debugging and the end time is null.

Comment: What is this date format? 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A' I don't recognize it, try changing it to 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'

Comment: changed all date formats to that format and nothing changed when i ran the program

Comment: What do you see before the data is coming to the server? (you can see it in your network tab if using chrome)

Comment: Wow. I was monitoring it with network tab and the calendar worked and updated. All I did was change the format of the date in the index to 
                format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'            How do I mark this as solved? thank you so much @Ziv Weissman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format of the date is not a valid one for c# automated binding.

```
'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A'
```

Change it to

```
'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'
```

Comment: Thank you. I should also mention that I had to format as 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss' in order for it to work on my computer. I have no Idea why puting the month first made it work but it did.