# Jquery Event Calendar and Microsoft Azure problems

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, azure

I recently asked a question pertaining to my calendar project on here and got good results so I figure ill ask another question about it.

this is the tutorial I am following
http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2017/07/curd-operation-on-fullcalendar-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Unfortunately I lost my code I was working on recently when it comes to this project. But I just wanted to know before I restart coding again: **Why do events not load on a calendar(jquery and javascript) when I use an Azure database?** Specifically after a posting the events don't load. They will load when I use a regular sql database, but they will not load when using an Azure sql database. I can't find any information on a similar issue and am curious if this is a known issue to do with Json possibly?

Here is a snippet of code that fetches events from the backend:

```
FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
        function FetchEventAndRenderCalendar() {
            events = [];
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/home/GetEvents",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                        events.push({
                            eventID: v.EventID,
                            title: v.Subject,
                            description: v.Description,
                            start: moment(v.Start),
                            end: v.End != null ? moment(v.End) : null,
                            color: v.ThemeColor,
                            allDay: v.IsFullDay
                        });
                    })
```

I can't debug right now but maybe I will try to enter just part of the code so I can test why exactly using an azure database makes it so events don't load on the calendar.

Comment: what does "won't load" mean? Is there an error message anywhere on the client- or server- side? P.S. Bad luck for losing your code, hopefully in future you'll make backups :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do events not load on a calendar(jquery and javascript) when I use an Azure database?

I download the [demo code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6gb11RP24ngY01uWUl4TlBkSnc) from you mentioned tutorial. Then I change it to use Azure SQL, and it works correctly.

If we run the application locally, we need to add client IP to Azure SQL firewall to let client to access to the Azure SQL. WE could get more info about Azure SQL firewall from [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure#manage-firewall-rules-using-the-azure-portal).

[image]

The following is my details steps:

1.Replace the connectionstring to Azure SQL connectionstring

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="MyDatabaseEntities" connectionString="Server=tcp:sqlservername.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=databasename;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={user};Password={password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.Sqlclient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

2.Create a table with same schema with given Event table in the Azure sql database.

3.Remove the localdb and MyModel.xx related files

4.Add Event.cs and MyDatabaseEntities.cs file

```
  public class Event
{
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> End { get; set; }
    public string ThemeColor { get; set; }
    public bool IsFullDay { get; set; }
}
public partial class MyDatabaseEntities : DbContext
    {
        public MyDatabaseEntities()
            : base("name=MyDatabaseEntities")
        {
        }
        public virtual DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
    }
```

project file struct:

[image]

5.Test it locally,it works correctly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Tom Sun. I followed your instructions step by step and was able to get my calendar events to appear. I would also add that I needed to change the dates as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46371017/javascript-fullcalendar-datetime-is-messed-up/46373887#46373887)